# SharePoint Hosted App >> Unable to create termset

Tags: managed-metadata, sharepoint-hosted-app, term-store, term-set, term

I am creating termset in SharePoint Hosted App with below code. but it is giving error **Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.** Whereas logged  in user is owner for that group where i am creating this termset.

```
createTerm: function (termName) {
        var _this = this;
        //Current Context
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        //Current Taxonomy Session
        var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

        //Term Stores
        var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();

        //Term Store under which to create the term.
        var termStore = termStores.getByName(_this.termStoreName);

        //Term Set under which to create the term.
        var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(_this.termSetId);

        //Create new guid
        var termGuid = new SP.Guid.newGuid()

        //Name of the term, LCID and a new GUID for the term.
        var newTerm = termSet.createTerm(termName, 1033, termGuid.toString());

        newTerm.set_isAvailableForTagging(true);

        context.load(newTerm);

        context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            _this.termMetadataString = termName + ";" + termGuid.toString();
            _this.upsertAuditFormItem("Term Metadata string");
        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message())
            alert("Here it is throwing error. Which i mentioned earlier");
            AuditUtility.hideLoading();
        });
    },
```

Comment: Hi you are running managed metadata service application in sharepoint?

Comment: Managed Metadata service is up and running.

Comment: Have you applied taxonomy permission to app?

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your app doesn't have permission to write data to the term store.

To provide permission , go to the `Appmanifest.xml` file and provide write permission the `Taxonomy` scope.

[image]

Deploy the app again and it should work now.

Comment: Still i am facing same error.
**Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.**

Comment: you can try 2 things - 1) use the sharepoint admin account 2) change the permission from `write` to `full control`.

Comment: 1. Account with which i am logged in that is Admin only.
2. In Taxonomy, there are only two permissions defined, one is Read and another is Write. So How can we switch to Full Control?